# RegExp matching url w/o affect email address

Tags: javascript, regex

Supposed that I have a block of text like this:

```
My site: http://www.mysite.com,
drop me an email at foo@bar.com
```

I want to replace url & email address to convert text to link.

I then used this pattern for email:

```
text.replace(/([\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*)/gi, replacement);
```

and below pattern for url:

```
text.replace(/((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi, replacement);
```

But the url pattern screw up my email pattern, the last result become like:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@<a href="bar.com">bar.com</a>>bar.com</a>
```

Is there any better pattern for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Include `(?:ht|f)tps?://` for matching the URL

Comment: then how to match an url w/o protocol part? for example: www.foo.bar.com.

Comment: hey! would you please give me a reason, downvoter?

Comment: Think about "protecting" a change you have made. You could temporarily store the email when found and replace it with `emailGoesHere`; do the same with URL; then put both of them back with proper modifications.

Comment: I have no idea why i cannot edit my question? I thought about that too. But it will be hard & more harder if number of match value increase. I also thought about replace dot (.) in email to asterisk then replace it back after the url replacement is done. But i really have no idea how to replace dot in matched part ($1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with this regex:

```
/(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/.+\b)|(\b[\w.]+@(?=.*?\.)[\w.]+\b)/g
```

And replace it with:

```
<a href="$1$2">$1$2</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/38mld)

Comment: Thank you Amit, your pattern is really cool. But if I want to add "mailto:" prefix to email address then?

Comment: sorry, you have to it again after replacing this

Comment: ah! you really gave me a very good idea Amit. Thank you my friend.

Comment: glad to have helped you

Comment: A valid email address can have a period before the @ symbol: `john.doe@gmail.com` for example. That is not captured by your pattern - but could easily be covered by changing `\w+@` to `[\w.]+@` in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your core problem will be that your 'URL' pattern also contains an '@' so it'll 'match' your email address as well.

However, I would also suggest that your patterns are way too complicated. 
Something like:

email pattern should be something like:

> [\w.+]+\@[\w.]+

url pattern something like:

> https?://[\w.]+

It won't catch some of the more unusual, but otherwise valid patterns that could be used for URLs (that latter for example, won't catch URLs for CGI GETs). Neither does either really validate the data. But you don't want a regex for that in the first place really.

Comment: actually, I made a mistake when copy & paste my url pattern. The real one is: /((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi